# How do I implement a camera in my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed the below tutorial
https://xamarinhelp.com/use-camera-take-photo-xamarin-forms/
(I installed version 3.1.3)

But I get this error:
CS0103  The name 'PhotoImage' does not exist in the current context

In this method:

```
private async void CameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });

    if (photo != null)
        PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
}
```

I am new to Xamarin and am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: If that happens you didn’t follow the tutorial exactly. Did you put the control named PhotoImage onto the form? Is the code in the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shared sample , you can have a check whether `Xaml` contains `PhotoImage` :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" />
    <Button x:Name="CameraButton" Text="Take Photo" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```